# How can I copy files between localhost and server using git?

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have server on Ubuntu, where i host many projects. Files visible to world in `/var/www`

After working on my localhost with project "projectName" I open FTP client and send files to server. I want to make a remote repo on my server and I want to have newest files in folder `/var/www/projectName`

Is there any simple way to do that? I have read GIT manual, but they always write about having only repo on server, not to store newest files in specific directory.

I'm the only person who will be pushing files to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends, if you have ssh access to the server, yes, just create the git repo on the server then pull it locally and then `git push`, you will have to create a git hook on the server to auto "checkout" the latest changes.

server :

```
cd /var/www/site.com
git init
git add -A
git commit -a -m 'initial'
cd .git
echo "#!/bin/sh" > hooks/post-receive
echo "git checkout -f" >> hooks/post-receive
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

local :

```
git clone user@host:/var/www/site.com
cd site.com
--edit stuff--
git commit
git push
```

Comment: Now when I try to push i got: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly. Any idea why? ssh works when I type ssh user@host.com

Comment: problem solved, when cloning use: git clone user@host:/path/to/project

Comment: My bad, that what happens when I don't get enough coffee before answering things, I'll edit my post to have the correct answer.